# Python: Combine several scripts into one shell script

Tags: python, shell, cups

I have three scripts:
The first one generates a pdf with a random sentence.
The second one crops the pdf.
The third one prints the cropped pdf.

How do I combine the three scripts into one shell script?

First script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 3

import fpdf
import random

def GetRandomFontFromFile(filename):
  with open(filename,"r") as f:
    lines = f.read().split("\n")
  return lines[random.randint(0, len(lines)-1)]

randomfont = GetRandomFontFromFile("fontlist.txt")

def GetRandomLineFromFile(filename):
  with open(filename,"r") as f:
    lines = f.read().split("\n")
  return lines[random.randint(0, len(lines)-1)]

line = GetRandomLineFromFile("sentenceslist.txt")

pdf = fpdf.FPDF('P','mm',(80,120))
pdf.add_page()
pdf.add_font('', '', (randomfont), uni=True)
pdf.set_font('','',size=12)
pdf.multi_cell(0,4.5,(line))
pdf.output('output-not-cropped.pdf', 'F')
```

Second script:

```
pdfcrop --margins '0 0 24 0' output-not-cropped.pdf output-cropped.pdf
```

Third script:

```
lp -d <printer> output-cropped.pdf
```

Comment: Why don't you just join all as a python program which does all that 3 things?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to launch these 3 script you can write the same commands you use to launch them in your term. It could be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

python3 script1.py && python3 script2.py && python3 script3.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple bash script (let's name it `executor.sh`):

*executor.sh*

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

python3 script1.py
pdfcrop --margins '0 0 24 0' output-not-cropped.pdf output-cropped.pdf
lp -d <printer> output-cropped.pdf
```

and run it:
`./executor.sh`